# Sonata Custom Action

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I use Sonata Admin and in list entity I need add my custom action, I did like the sonata document [screen](http://uploads.ru/Pj4oh.png), but when I use filter field or click for page, [screen](http://uploads.ru/njYHS.png), pagination my action disappears, and I have button select. How add custom action and how to make that is not lost?

```
class CRUDController extends Controller
{

public function cloneAction()
{
    $object = $this->admin->getSubject();
    $id = $object->getId();
    return new RedirectResponse($this->generateUrl('admin_index', array('id' => $id))); //this is my custom action
}
}
```

add in service CRUD

```
        <service id="sonata.admin.developer" class="Artel\AdminBundle\Controller\DeveloperSonataController">
        <tag name="sonata.admin" manager_type="orm" group="Content" label="Developer"/>
        <argument />
        <argument>Artel\ProfileBundle\Entity\Developer</argument>
        <argument>ArtelAdminBundle:CRUD</argument>
        <argument />
        <call method="setTranslationDomain">
            <argument>ArtelAdminBundle</argument>
        </call>
        <call method="addChild">
            <argument type="service" id="sonata.news.admin.comment" />
        </call>
        </service>
```

create template

```
{# src/AppBundle/Resources/views/CRUD/list__action_clone.html.twig #}

//<a class="btn btn-sm" href="{{ admin.generateObjectUrl('clone', object) }}">clone</a>
```

add routing

```
class DeveloperSonataController extends Admin
{
protected function configureRoutes(RouteCollection $collection)
{
    $collection->add('clone', $this->getRouterIdParameter().'/clone');
}
```

and in finished I have controller

```
class DeveloperSonataController extends Admin
{
protected function configureRoutes(RouteCollection $collection)
{
    $collection->add('clone', $this->getRouterIdParameter().'/clone');
}

// Fields to be shown on create/edit forms
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $formMapper

        ->add('firstName', null, array('label' => 'Developer\'s First Name', 'max_length' => 255))
        ->add('lastName', null, array('label' => 'Developer\'s Last Name', 'max_length' => 255))
        ->add('qualification', 'choice', array('label' => 'Speciality',
            'choices' => array('Frontend' => 'Frontend', 'Backend' => 'Backend', 'Full stack' => 'Full stack'),'attr'=> array('class'=>'qualif'), 'required' => false))
        ->add('level', 'choice', array('label' => 'Professional Level', 'max_length' => 255,
            'choices' => array('Junior' => 'Junior', 'Middle' => 'Middle', 'Senior' => 'Senior')))
        ->add('tags', 'tags', array('label' => 'Tags','required' => false))
        ->add('main_skill', 'mainSkill', array('label' => 'Main Skill', 'required' => true, 'mapped' => true, 'attr' => array('placeholder' => 'Select your skills ...', 'class'=>'main_skill') ))
        ->add('skills', 'skills', array('label' => 'Skills','required' => false))
        ->add('english', 'choice', array('label' => 'English Level', 'max_length' => 255,
            'choices' => array('Basic' => 'Basic', 'Intermediate' => 'Intermediate', 'Advanced' => 'Advanced')))
        ->add('rate', null, array('label' => 'Rate $/h', 'max_length' => 255))
    ;
}

// Fields to be shown on filter forms
protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
{
    $datagridMapper
        ->add('email')
        ->add('telephone')
        ->add('skype')
        ->add('username')
        ->add('firstName')
        ->add('lastName')
        ->add('main_skill')
        ->add('skills')
        ->add('level')
        ->add('rate')
        ->add('english')
        ->add('location')
        ->add('country')

        ->add('created', 'doctrine_orm_date_range', array('field_type'=>'sonata_type_date_range_picker',))
    ;
}

// Fields to be shown on lists
protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
{
    $listMapper
        ->addIdentifier('id')//how change routig in addIdentifier??
        ->add('username')
        ->add('firstName')
        ->add('lastName')
        ->add('main_skill')
        ->add('level')
        ->add('rate')
        ->add('english')
        ->add('email')
        ->add('location')
        ->add('country')
        ->add('created')
        ->add('image', 'string', array('template' => 'SonataMediaBundle:MediaAdmin:list_image.html.twig'))
        ->add('_action', 'actions', array(
            'actions' => array(
                'show' => array(),
                'edit' => array(),
                'clone' => array(
                    'template' => 'ArtelAdminBundle:CRUD:list__action_clone.html.twig'
                )
            )
        ))
    ;
}
```

}

Comment: no solution for this?